# Iterating through a string, and switch statements: C++

Tags: c++

I was writing some code, and came across some trouble. I wanted to write a function that checks if a string has any vowels, and tried to do it through a for loop with a switch statement inside. Apparently, it doesn't work and never returns true for some reason.

```
bool scanStr(string userInp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < userInp.size(); i++) {
        switch (userInp[i])
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            return true;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried just testing if the program was actually iterating through the string, and it was, so I don't understand why in the function, it always returns false?

```
int main() {
    string userInp;
    string pigLatin;

    cout << "Please enter a string to convert to pig Latin: " << endl;
    cin >> userInp;
    cout << endl;

    // tests
    for (int i = 0; i < userInp.size(); i++) { //checking if it actually iterates
        cout << userInp[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    if (scanStr(userInp))
        cout << "it has a vowel" << endl;
    else
        cout << "no vowel" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

At first I thought that it was because the loop kept on continuing even though there was a break statement after the last case, but I'm not entirely sure if that is the reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is wrong. I'll fix it for you

Comment: Your loop counter `i` should be of type `std::size_t`, because `userInp.size()` might not always fit into a signed `int`.

Comment: Also note that the `break;` statement after the `return true;` statement is dead code and will never be executed.

Comment: Read about `std::string::find_first_of`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was, if any character wasn't vowel, that function imediatelly returned false. Also use `const &`. `const` allows you to pass const strings and reference saves some time, because C++ doesn't have to copy whole string.

```
bool scanStr(const string & userInp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < userInp.size(); i++) {
        switch (userInp[i])
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I donno, still new to C++ so I am not familiar with all the functions they have just yet

Comment: This is C function, but it is pure desing thing. It would spare you some lines of code. But definetelly look up references! If you are familiar with C and pointers, than reference is kind of a pointer in C++ way.

Comment: So far, the closest I've been able to mess with references are the & sign, but the * thingy seemed a bit more convoluted for me at this point :P

Comment: It's actually pretty simple. Look it up :) I hope I helped, I'd really like to get C++ badge here ...

Comment: _"No performance issue"_ I'd expect the switch as it is to be faster.

Comment: @RainbowTom What do you mean by "no performance issue"? There is a slight performance overhead if you use `std::tolower` in the `switch` and remove the uppercase labels. I just bencmarked this on my system with 2300MB strings, and with GCC the overhead seems to be minimal, but with Clang, a version using `std::tolower` seems to take **at least 12 times** as much time on my system. Using a regular `switch` or even some `static bool const isLower[255u] = { false, ..., };`  lookup table is usually faster than calling an external function with no performance constraints.

Comment: Well, that suprises me. I thought, that such simple function wouldn't be such a deal.

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest that you extract the logic of vowel testing into its own function:

```
bool is_vowel(char x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
    case 'e':
    case 'E':
    case 'i':
    case 'I':
    case 'o':
    case 'O':
    case 'u':
    case 'U':
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can use a standard algorithm instead of a loop:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool contains_vowel(const std::string& str)
{
    return std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), is_vowel);
}
```

(I renamed `scanStr` to `contains_vowel` because that name is much more descriptive.)

Comment: compleeeeeeeeeetely lost here, but I sort of understand!

Comment: "Are all characters in a string vowels?" is just one concrete example of "Do all elements in a sequence satisfy some predicate?", and the C++ standard libary offers an algorithm for that.

Comment: for being the only answer to promote decoupling and use of std algorithms. more like this please, +1

Answer (score 5):

Drop this lines from your function:

```
    default:
        return false;
```

They make your function return `false` on the *first* non-vowel it encounters.

You only want to return `false` if you reach the *end* of the loop and haven't returned `true` yet.

```
bool scanStr(string userInp) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < userInp.size(); i++) 
    {
        switch (userInp[i])
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

A better approach in modern C++ would be:

```
bool scanStr(const std::string& userInp) 
{
    for (const auto c : userInp) 
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

But if you don't know what it means, don't worry about it now, your book or tutorial will explain soon enough.

Comment: I am confused, suppose I had a string "Hello", using H as the first iteration, in my code, it would have gone to the default and returned false, but there is no break statement, so shouldn't the code continue?

Comment: @Panthy No, once you `return` your function is over and the value (if any) is returned to the caller.

Comment: I see... suppose I had a variable bool X and instead of returning true/false, I place the value of true/false into X and finally return X out of the loop, would that work also, hypothetically?

Comment: @Panthy: You can exit a loop with all of the flow control statements (except "continue"):  `break`, `goto`, `return`.  (except `break` wouldn't work in this case because it would break from the `switch` instead.)

Comment: @Panthy Hypothetically, if you don't make any mistakes, yes, that could work. It would be more complicated and error-prone though. Try it, it might be a good exercise.

Comment: @Panthy:  Not if you write `flag = true;` and `flag = false` where you have `return` at the moment.  You would just be testing whether the *last* character is a vowel.  It would work if you initialized the flag false, and set it true on a vowel, and then returned it.  That would involve pointless work scanning the rest of the string though.

Comment: @nvoigt:  You don't need that "break" after the "return".  Good compilers will warn about it (unreachable code).

Comment: Also:  Can I encourage the use of loops like `for (const auto c : userInp)` - far clearer it is looping over the whole string.

Comment: @MartinBonner Included the "for" and const reference parameter passing, although I think that's too early to really understand for the OP.

Comment: No, I have seen that before, and remember that the : operator in the for loop goes through the entire string. Thanks for the suggestion and reminder!

Comment: Actually, I do not understand the parameter you put in for the function itself, 1. Why are we making it a const? 2.Why use & if we aren't going to be changing its value or anything?

Comment: @Panthy: To avoid copying it needlessly.

Answer (score 0):

First the compiler will turn the switch case into a lookup table, then `auto` will be decided as a data-type by the compiler based on the value assigned (in this case it's `char`).

*Or just give it to your compiler, it knows how to do it.*

```
bool scanStr(string userInp)
{
    for(auto c : userInp)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'a': case 'A':
            case 'e': case 'E':
            case 'i': case 'I':
            case 'o': case 'O':
            case 'u': case 'U':
            case 'y': case 'Y':

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```